# A less restrictive definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

The standard definition of continuity also called $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for a real function f(x) at point $x=a$ is that given any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta: |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.
Going by what I understood from this definition is that for a function to be continuous at point $x=a$, we want that there should be points as close to (a,f(a)) as we want in a sense so that as we near the point, it looks somewhat like a continuous line or strip.

However, if this is indeed the case, why don't we define continuity as follows :

A function f is continuous at $x=a$, if given any $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists x : d((x,f(x), (a,f(a))))<\epsilon$. For instance, taking d to be the standard metric on $R^2$,

f is continuous on a, if given $\epsilon>0, \exists x \neq a : \sqrt{(x-a)^2+{(f(x)-f(a))}^2}<\epsilon$.

This seems to be less restrictive as we don't force the condition of getting close to $\epsilon$ in the entire region, but only one point.
Is my intuitive understanding of continuity flawed? Or are both the definitions equivalent? Any comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can define whatever you want, but I doubt this would be a useful definition. As an example, the characteristic function of the rational numbers would be a continuous function.

Comment: Your standard definition of continuity isn't correct; it is required that $\delta > 0$.

Comment: As you said continuous line is important here.  But with the definition given here you miss this property. As the first comment pointed out the graph of character istic function would have been a continuous line,  not an intiutive thing.

Comment: FWIW, the "characteristic function of rationals" mentioned in other comments is $i_{\mathbb Q}(x):=\begin{cases}1&x\text{ rational}\\0&x\text{ irrational}\end{cases}$, and, with your definition, it would be continuous at every real $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable comments. This clears my doubt.